# How to do round-robin scheduling such that two players don't play each other again in the whole tournament

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, schedule

I have a list of users. E.g -

> 1,2,3,....100

These users belong to one city. There are similar lists for other cities.

I am using the round-robin scheduling algorithm to schedule matches between players belonging to same city. So if I want each player to play 3 matches, I run the algorithm 3 times instead of (No. of Users - 1). So for first stage this is okay.

Now next stage is inter-state i.e. between players from the whole state. So I want to use round robin algorithm but don't want players who played each before to play again. How can I achieve that.

This is my round-robin program:

```
$users = range(0, 99);
        $played_before = array();
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
            $played_before[$value] = array_rand($users,3);
        }
shuffle($users);
$no_of_matches_per_player = 3;
if( $length % 2 == 1){
            $users = array_push($users, 'x');
        }

        $mid = $length / 2;

        $l1 = array();
        $l2 = array();

        for ($i=0; $i < $no_of_matches_per_player ; $i++) { 
            $l1 = array_slice($users, 0, $mid);
            $l2 = array_slice($users, $mid);
            $l2 = array_reverse($l2);

            $round = Embed::zip($l1, $l2);
            array_push($schedule, $round);
            $insert = array(array_pop($users));
            array_splice( $users, 1, 0, $insert);
        }
```

I have created a test array $users and $played_before.

$played_before contains player_ids as keys and an array of players he has played as value.

Embed::zip function is similar to python's zip function. It zips the element at same index from two or more arrays. For e.g.
Array 1: 1,2,3
Array 2: 4,5,6
Zip function will return:
Array: ([0]=>array(1,4), [1]=>array(2,5), [2]=>array(3,6))

State are divided into cities and cities are divided into clubs.

So for e.g.

Club1 - 1,2,3,...10

Club2 - 11,12,13,...20

For city stage the users array is 1,2,3,...20 and I do a round robin scheduling on this array.

Then for state stage:

City1: 1,2,3,...20

City2: 21,22,23,....40

Now the users array will be 1,2,3,....40 and I have to round robin in a way that players who played in the previous stages don't play again

Comment: do you randomness in the schedule of matches ?

Comment: Yes I shuffle the users array. Sorry forgot to add that. Edited the program

Comment: so your problem is there are repeated matches in same players ?

Comment: Yes, after shuffling there can be repeated matches. Also in state stage the list will be of all users from city 1 to city k and I don't want players who have played before to play again.

Comment: can you give a simple example of how you want to schedule the matches between cities so that i can give you comprehesive ans

Comment: moreover in state stage do you want users in same city to play each other because that would be invalid right ?

Comment: State are divided into cities and cities are divided into clubs. So for e.g.
Club1 - 1,2,3,...10
Club2 - 11,12,13,...20
For city stage the users array is 1,2,3,...20 and I do a round robin  scheduling on this array.
Then for state stage:
City1: 1,2,3,...20
City2: 21,22,23,....40
Now the users array will be 1,2,3,....40 and I have to round robin in a way that players who played in the previous stages don't play again

Comment: Also the clubs might have different numbers of players under them.

Comment: So why not just put the different cities in different arrays and pick a player from two arrays for each match?

Comment: Okay, but there won't be only 2 cities, there can be any number of cities.

Comment: Not sure what will be the problem, then.

Comment: So I need to pick two array out of n number of arrays then randomly pick one element each out of the two arrays and check if they have played before or not. If not schedule a match between them else again pick two elements each. Repeat this until all players have k number of matches scheduled.

Right?

Comment: For instance. There might be something smarter.